# How long should an installer wait for a healthy internet connection?

Tags: download, speed

I have a web installer that downloads the necessary files from internet to install the software. This works perfectly in a high speed connection(multi channel leased line).

But when tested in normal broadband connection, it fails. When the speed drops below `1 kbps` for `10 seconds`, the installer exits showing an error message. Now this is quite frustrating as I found that it will be impossible to install the software in normal internet connection.

**What should be the optimal time it should wait for the speed to come over a tolerable limit?
What should be the tolerable limit also?**

Currently it is `10 sec` and `1kbps`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about *Application* Experience and not **User** Experience. Programmer would probably be a better Place for this question.

Answer (score 2):

Does it matter? I would say that as soon as the internet connection actually works, it is fine no matter how long it will take to download the necessary binaries. 
What is important is that the users gets feedback about this. E.g. current throughput (kbps), and some kind of progress indication which can be graphical and/or in text (xxxx Mbytes of total yyyy Bbytes are downloaded).